# how to deploy same build to production from Stage - using create react app

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

Pleas help. My deployment environment won't support to move a separate build in production.
What i need to do is, move same build which is in stage to production.
But i have different api urls for stage and productions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It looks like you can probably keep your stage and live vars in a separate file, and set the real .env file in a package.json script when you want to deploy.

See **Environment specific .env files** in this post: https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d